# Consume mouseMoved Event

Tags: swift, macos

I'm trying to write an application that will deny the mouse cursor access to a specific area of the screen. This application, importantly, is running solely in the `MenuBarExtra`, and thus has no main UI. This application will only be available on macOS, so mobile devices are a non-issue.

In Swift, I've created a Tap in order to listen for the mouseMoved event:

```swift
let eventMask = (1 << CGEventType.mouseMoved.rawValue);
currentTap = CGEvent.tapCreate(
    tap: .cghidEventTap,
    place: .headInsertEventTap,
    options: .defaultTap,
    eventsOfInterest: CGEventMask(eventMask),
    callback: cgEventCallback,
    userInfo: nil
);
                
let runLoopSource = CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, currentTap, 0)
CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), runLoopSource, .commonModes)
```

Now according to the [Apple/Swift documentation for the CGEventTapCallBack](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgeventtapcallback#discussion), returning `nil` inside of this handler *should* delete the event:

```swift
func cgEventCallback(proxy: CGEventTapProxy, type: CGEventType, event: CGEvent, refcon: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) -> Unmanaged<CGEvent>? {
    return nil;
}
```

Obviously I would have some logic in there, but returning `nil` in this event for mouseMoved does not seem to delete the event.

Is there just something I'm missing here? I'm pretty new to Swift itself, and the ins and outs of the Apple ecosystem from a programming perspective, so it's definitely possible I've just done something silly.

Thanks!

Example code:

```swift
func cgEventCallback(proxy: CGEventTapProxy, type: CGEventType, event: CGEvent, refcon: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) -> Unmanaged<CGEvent>? {
    return nil;
}

@main
struct PlaygroundApp: App {
    @State var currentNumber: String = "0"
    @State var currentTap: CFMachPort? = nil;
    
    var body: some Scene {
        MenuBarExtra(currentNumber, systemImage: "\(currentNumber).square") {
            Button("Test Event") {
                let eventMask =
                (1 << CGEventType.mouseMoved.rawValue)
                | (1 << CGEventType.keyDown.rawValue)
                | (1 << CGEventType.keyUp.rawValue);
                
                currentTap = CGEvent.tapCreate(
                    tap: .cghidEventTap,
                    place: .headInsertEventTap,
                    options: .defaultTap,
                    eventsOfInterest: CGEventMask(eventMask),
                    callback: cgEventCallback,
                    userInfo: nil
                );
                                
                let runLoopSource = CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, currentTap, 0)
                CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), runLoopSource, .commonModes)
                currentNumber = "1";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you test this?

Comment: @Willeke I have a button in the Menu Bar that creates the Tap upon click. I receive the events just fine and can print them out to the console. But returning `nil` still allows the mouse cursor to move, which is unexpected.

Comment: Mouse movement causes the cursor to move and generates mouse moved events. Blocking the events does not prevent the cursor from moving.

Comment: @Willeke I would expect the same functionality as I do if I were to include keyDown and keyUp. If I return nil for either of those events, the event does not process and no key is typed.

Comment: It does work the same, the event is blocked but the key is pressed. The movement of the cursor is not because of the events. Sending an event does not move the cursor. If you return `nil` then the event still happened but it isn't reported to the apps.

Comment: @Willeke do yo know how to prevent mouse movement?

Comment: @narduk if you mean cursor movement, then no.